# Directory search returns incorrect number of files

Tags: python, linux, file, linux-mint

I'm using Python3, Linux Mint and Visual Studio Code.

Also using, the following code to see whether any evtx files exist in a directory:

```
    print("Number of EVTX files in each individual folder:")
path = '/home/user/CI5235_K1915147_Sam/evtx_logs'
folders = ([name for name in os.listdir(path)])
targets = []
for folder in folders:
    contents = os.listdir(os.path.join(path,folder))
    for i in contents:
        if i.endswith('evtx'):
            targets.append(i)
    print(folder, len(contents))
print ("Total number of evtx files = " + str(len(targets)))

print()
```

It searches the directory and sub-directories of evtx_logs and lists every file within. How would I be able to modify it so that it ONLY counts evtx files as it is currently counting other .xml files that are also in the folder too.

Comment: Either `os.path.splitext` or `glob` can be your friends here.

Comment: That is great! How would I go about implementing that into my code? Import the glob module and from there? I'm fairly new to Python!

Comment: I already have os imported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified your existing code to use `glob` as suggested above.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import glob
print("Number of EVTX files in each individual folder:")
path = '/home/user/CI5235_K1915147_Sam/evtx_logs'
folders = ([name for name in os.listdir(path)])
targets = []
for folder in folders:
    contents = glob.glob(os.path.join(path,folder)+"/*evtx")
    for i in contents:
        targets.append(i)
    print(folder, len(contents))
print ("Total number of evtx files = " + str(len(targets)))

print()
```

The problem with your own code is that you're printing the length of contents (which will always be all the files in the directory) rather than the number of matches from `if i.endswith('evtx'):`.

Comment: Thank you Tink! I’m fairly new to Python so this is a great help! It’s people like you who really make me feel comfortable in the SO community!

Comment: You're welcome, and I'm pleased to hear that ... these comments are likely to be removed, though, as they don't add value to the site overall ;) ... feel free to "accept" the answer if it does what you expected.

Comment: It works!!!!  Shame if the comments removed... you could always add my discord ;)

Comment: That's odd ... it works (as designed) for me ... https://justpaste.it/1nm9v

Comment: Just re-edited my comment! I was misreading the terminal :S